# How to play audio after user done with phone call automatically

Tags: android, phone-state-listener

I am using below code in onCreate() method, which `pauses music` when someone `calls` me or i do `make a call`, but here i need one more thing, once user done with call automatically start playing song again where it left (not from starting)

Still user has to click on play button again to start audio

```
PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
            if(mPlayer!=null) {

                if(mPlayer.isPlaying()){ 
                    mPlayer.pause();
                    }
            }

            } else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
            } else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {

            if(mPlayer!=null) {

                if(mPlayer.isPlaying()){ 
                    mPlayer.pause();
                    }
                }
            }
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            }
            };

            TelephonyManager mgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            if(mgr != null) {
            mgr.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
            } 
    } // end of onCreate() method
```

Answer (score 1):

When the call ends the state will go back to idle, so you should resume the music in the idle state:

```
else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
    if(!mPlayer.isPlaying()){ 
                mPlayer.start();  
                }
        }
```

Comment: but i am getting : The method play() is undefined for the type MediaPlayer

Comment: mPlayer.play() was supposed to be pseudo, look at the MediaPlayer documenation to see how to resume the player. I believe it's mPlayer.start() you should use, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I also work on create music player, and below code work for me. Hope it help.
Also, you might need to create class to broadcast when calling, or working with VoIP...

```
private PhoneStateListener mPhoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING
                    || state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                mPlayer.pause();
                mTelephonyMgr.listen(mPhoneStateListener,
                        PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
            }
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        }
    };
```